# How does DHCP handle multiple scopes in the same subnet

Tags: networking, dhcp, udp

We are studying DHCP in our networking class and I have a Virtual Box in which I have set up 2 VMs - one of them is a Windows server and other is a Windows 10 workstation. 
I have added the DHCP server role on the Windows server machine and I have added the following two scopes:

192.168.1.1 -192.168.1.20

192.168.1.30 - 192.168.1.40

I have added 192.168.1.21-29 in the exclusions list.

My question is which scope does the sever use when handing out IPs to my Windows WS? (both my Windows server and Windows WS are in the same network and domain)
Does it choose the scope randomly or is there a process it follows?

I was going through the [this](https://superuser.com/questions/356567/how-does-dhcp-distribute-or-choose-which-ip-to-give-within-the-scope) thread and in this case the server handed out this particular IP becuase it was leased previously by the same device.

But what if the device is requesting IP for the first time? Which scope would it choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DHCP protocol standard does not specify how a server should handle such a situation, so it's left as an implementation detail.

So the question of how the particular DHCP server software you're using handles it is something that you can only know if the vendor has documented it, or if someone has reverse-engineered its behavior and published their findings, or if you can reverse-engineer it yourself or inspect the source code.